# SSIS : Import data from Excel and CSV file to SQL Server DB

Tags: ssis

I have a folder which contains Multiple Files as shown Below
Files:

```
Excel_File1 - 3 Sheets (10 Rows: 4 Columns on each sheet)
Excel_File2 - 2 Sheets (8 Rows: 4 Columns on each sheet)
CSV_File1 ( 25 Rows : 4 Columns)
CSV_File2 (3 Rows : 4 Columns)
```

Excel and CSV contains 4 column of Data `(Column1, Column2,Column3 Column4)`
Same structure of Table is create in SQL Server DB. Need to push data from EXCEL and CSV File to DB.
I know there is a way that we can use two Foreach loop containers one for Excel (which contains nested for looping through sheets) and one for CSV and then we can union it. But i want dynamic solution so that i can include another file type in future instead of creating whole structure again.

Comment: XLSX excel or XLS?

Comment: Assume anything.. May be XLSX.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you applying?  Not all file types are supported in the Connection Manager (for example, MS Project), which may require custom coding and adding to that specific references to handle the dynamic file type range.  The first objective is to define a list of all of the file types you foresee the SSIS package needing to handle and their configuration.